# QGIS2Web cannot click url as popup disappears

Tags: qgis, javascript, qgis2web

I have successfully created an interactive map using QGIS2Web. I can hover over the polygons and see the url in the popup, but cannot click on it or access the url as the popup disappears when I maneuver off the icon and onto the popup.

I followed the [tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html) to do this. There is an [example map](https://storage.googleapis.com/qgis-tutorials/qgis2web/index.html) which you could see has this problem.

If you cannot click on the link but just having the url has no use.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You should accept answers occasionally. You are a help vampire of the highest order, the kind of person who makes me want to give up answering questions entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to be able to interact with the popups, such as by clicking on links, then uncheck "Show popups on hover" in the qgis2web dialog.

Comment: I did try but does not fix the problem. This just stop highlighting when hover over the polygons.

Comment: So sorry - I got my options confused. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Seems like you have to uncheck both "Show popups on hover" and "Highlight on hover"